# Kernel of matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

The following matrix is given

$A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

(i) What is the kernel of A?
(ii) What do you know about the solution of $Ax = b$ if $\ker(A)=\{0\}$?

Applying theorem of Gauß-Jordan we get after one step

$$A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \sim A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

therefore $x_2 = -x_3$ and $x_1 = x_3$ yielding in

$$ \ker(A) = \operatorname{span}\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^\intercal \} $$

so dimension of the kernel is 1.

(ii)
If the kernel is only the null vector, then all columns of A are linear independent, which means A has full rank and is invertible. Therefore Ax=b has only one solution.
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Correct✅ There are various ways of interpretating.$\ker (A) =\{0\}$ implies columns of $A$ are L.I and $Ax=b$ implies $b$ is the linear combination of the columns of $A$ .Coefficients of the combination is unique!

Comment: $(ii)$ needs a proof. But in fact $Ax=b$ then implies $x=A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}b$, so that $x$ is unique, and we are done.

Comment: It would be better if this question was broken up in to different questions.  some parts seem to be misleading and poorly worded at best. It would be better for you on getting feedback in the future.